# Fuzzily Gem: undefined method `fuzzily_searchable'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm having an issue with the Fuzzily Gem being undefined, but working perfectly within my rails console.

Here is a link to the repository: https://github.com/mezis/fuzzily

I followed the instructions on the repository:

You'll need to setup 2 things:

- a trigram model (your search index) and its migration
- the model you want to search for

Create an ActiveRecord model in your app (this will be used to store a "fuzzy index" of all the models and fields you will be indexing):

```
class Trigram < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Fuzzily::Model
end
```

Create a migration for it:

```
class AddTrigramsModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  extend Fuzzily::Migration
end
```

Instrument your model:

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  # assuming my_stuffs has a 'name' attribute
  fuzzily_searchable :name
end
```

Note: The name part in the following method calls refers to the `:name` field. Replace it to match your searchable attribute.

Index your model (will happen automatically for new/updated records):

```
Vendor.bulk_update_fuzzy_name
```

---

In my rails console, I can run:

```
Vendor.find_by_fuzzy_name('name', :limit => 2)
```

and it successfully returns all Vendor models with 'name' in their name.

The error is coming from the Vendor.rb file:

[image]

Here is my full trace:

```
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
app/models/vendor.rb:2:in `<class:Vendor>'
app/models/vendor.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `block in load_file'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_file'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:526:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
app/controllers/vendors_controller.rb:8:in `index'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
web-console (2.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:39:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.4) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
/Users/danieljeffords/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:155:in `handle'
/Users/danieljeffords/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:109:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in start'
/Users/danieljeffords/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in start'
/Users/danieljeffords/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:96:in `each'
/Users/danieljeffords/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:96:in `block in start'
/Users/danieljeffords/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:76:in `loop'
/Users/danieljeffords/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:76:in `start'
/Users/danieljeffords/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:12:in `run'
/Users/danieljeffords/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/bin/nack_worker:4:in `<main>'
```

There is an open issue within the Fuzzily repository that asks this question ( https://github.com/mezis/fuzzily/issues/53 ), but it hasn't had a response in the past couple of months. If any of you have dealt with this or have ideas for how to solve it I would be most appreciative! I'd be happy to provide any additional information!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try restarting application? Not sure if it'll work but always worth a try...

Comment: @JoeKennedy As simple as "did you switch it off and then back on?" is, it really is quite frequently the correct answer! I had a redundant server running on a different version trying to listen to the same port.

You are a fantastic human being!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, the OP was able to solve the problem by restarting the server. All set here!